# how to print a specific columns in a table using java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, php

is there anyway to exclude a column in a table? i have a table with options in them for every row i want to exclude during print process.

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style = "position : relative;    left : 0px; top : 0px; width : 100%; height : 10%" id = "tableitems">
 <thead>
        <th><center>ID</center> </th>
        <th><center>Item Name</center> </th>
        <th><center>Brand</center> </th>
        <th><center>Initial Price</center> </th>
        <th><center>Sales Price</center> </th>
        <th><center>Quantity</center> </th>
        <th><center>Dealer</center> </th>
        <th><center>Edit</center> </th>
        <th><center>Order</center> </th>
        <th><center>Defective</center> </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($rows as $row){
        if($row["Quantity"] < 10){
            print "<tr style = 'background-color : crimson; color : black' >";
        }else if($row["Quantity"] < 20) {
            print "<tr style = 'background-color : yellow; color : black' >";
        }else{
        }
print "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['ItemName'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['Brand'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['InitialPrice'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row['SalesPrice'] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row["Quantity"] . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $row["Dealer"] . "</td>";
print "<td><a href='Update.php?id=" . $row["ID"] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
print "<td><a href = '#!' onclick='show_overlay(" . $row['ID'] . ")'>Order</a></td>";
print "<td><a href = '#!' onclick='reorder(" . $row['ID'] . ")'>Defective</a></td>";
print "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
```

i have this print that gets the table values to problem is it also includes the options in the table is there anyway to exclude some columns to the table?

```
 <script>   
 function printData(){
 var divToPrint=document.getElementById("tableitems");
 newWin= window.open("");
 newWin.document.write("<center><h1>Meng and Mher</h1><p>List of Items</p> </center>");
 newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
 newWin.print();
 newWin.close();
 }

 $('btnprint').on('click',function(){
 printData();
 })
 </script>
```

Comment: what do you mean `options`? simplest way perhaps would be to have a rule in your print stylesheet that hides certain cells maybe

Comment: i want to exclude in the print the last 3 columns because its a link

Comment: apply a class to those last three table cells that contain the links and add a rule to your stylesheet ( assuming you have a print stylesheet ) or, in the javascript function, remove the table cells using dom methods

Comment: @RamRaider Wow man. You read my mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a line to print css into the new window to hide the nth-column like below

```
newWin.document.write("<style> td:nth-child(2){display:none;} </style>");
```