# how to print HTML table in a printer using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
function readingTable(){
const res=[...document.querySelectorAll("#stockinboundedittable tr")].slice(1).map(tr=>
  Object.fromEntries(
[...tr.querySelectorAll("input")].slice(1).map(inp=>[inp.id.replace(/.*stockinbound/,"").replace(/\d+$/,""),inp.value])));
document.getElementById("demoSpan").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(res);
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;   border-collapse: collapse;  text-align: center;" id="stockinboundedittable">
      
        <tr>
          <th style="display:none;">subcategory</th>
          <th>Sl.No</th>
          <!--<th>I.U.Code</th>-->
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th> old stock</th>
          <th> new stock</th>
          <th> Total Stock</th>
          <th> qty</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
     
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_2</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound1" value="1" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname1" value="Fresh Goat Meat - Curry Cut" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock1" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock1" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock1" value="30" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut1">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_5</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound2" value="2" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname2" value="Everest - Kasur Methi" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock2" value="0" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock2" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock2" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut2">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_13</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound3" value="3" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname3" value="Fresh Coconut Milk 150 ml" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock3" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock3" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock3" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut3">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_5</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound4" value="4" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname4" value="Sakthi - Chicken Masala" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock4" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock4" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock4" value="30" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty4">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut4">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_2</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound5" value="5" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname5" value="Goat Bones - Regular Soup Pack" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock5" value="0" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock5" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock5" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty5">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut5">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </table>
    
    <button onclick="readingTable()">View table as json array</button>
    <span id="demoSpan"></span>
```

### what i have

1.here i have been displaying some data's inside '' tag inside ''

2.Then i got data as json arrays using javascript

### What I needed

1. now I have to print values from the only sl.no, item name and qty in a printer with A4 sheet size using javascript

### for example

| sl.no | itemname | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fish | 2 |
| 2 | chicken | 2 |
| 3 | goat | 2 |
| 4 | crap | 2 |

*have to print like this from my table in a printer using javascript
*i have to print in printer in the example format

Comment: And what have you tried so far to accomplish the stated goal? Please add your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to print a specific columns in a table using java script or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393053/how-to-print-a-specific-columns-in-a-table-using-java-script-or-jquery)

Comment: It's much easier with CSS. Create an own stylesheet for printing, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/media